# Incremental copy between Hadoop Clusters (using Spark) given that FALCON deprecated

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

Given that FALCON is deprecated and distcp cannot do incremental copies of data that are not in separate ' nice slices', how would one copy in a sqoop-like way between two Hadoop clusters?

Can Spark attach to 2 clusters simultaneously? Never had the need to try this.

I can see many issues listed with cross realm HDFS aspects.

Comment: You can use Spark with two clusters by giving the full hdfs://namenode:port/path address

Comment: @cricket_007. Ok, thx for the tip. Seems like an answer as I can simulate sqoop incremental this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary:

- You can use Cloudera Replication Manager for HDFS:

  - for HDP, CDP and CDH environments. This is file based replication options.
  - for CDH you can do this for a given (set of) table(s).
- For KUDU there is no such option.
- You can use a Spark App with two clusters by giving the full hdfs://namenode:port/path address and "roll your own" logic. This applies o both HDFS/Hive, and KUDU Storage Manager in fact.